# SBT fails with `String.class is broken`

Tags: scala, sbt

`sbt` fails with a cryptic error on issuing any command (`compile`, `assembly`, `clean` or any other).

```
$ sbt --version                                                                                                                                                          
error: error while loading String, class file '/modules/java.base/java/lang/String.class' is broken
(class java.lang.NullPointerException/null)
```

I am on a machine running macOS, and `sbt` was installed via *homebrew*. I have tried upgrading to the latest versions of `sbt` (*1.3.10*), but the error still persists.

Comment: Where (in which directory) did you run sbt command? if you are running in a sbt project, check sbt version in `project/build.properties`

Comment: Which JDK do you have installed?

Comment: Hi, the issue seems to have been because of JDK 13 becoming the default JDK version in `homebrew`. I have posted a solution below.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The issue is documented on the [SBT Download](https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html) page.

> Homebrew maintainers have added a dependency to JDK 13 because they want to use more brew dependencies ([brew#50649](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/50649)). This causes sbt to use JDK 13 even when java available on PATH is JDK 8 or 11. To prevent sbt from running on JDK 13, install [jEnv](https://www.jenv.be/) or switch to using [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/).

I was able to resolve the problem by using JDK 8 via `jEnv`.

Comment: didn't work for me, but the other response about changing JDK in the sbt configs solved the issue in my case.

Answer (score 14):

Since sbt [documents](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Setup.html) JDK 8 and 11 as compatible versions

> We recommend AdoptOpenJDK JDK 8 or AdoptOpenJDK JDK 11

try controlling which JDK is used by sbt via `-java-home` setting which can be configured system-wide via `sbtopts` run configuration

```
/usr/local/etc/sbtopts
```

or per-project basis via

```
<project-root>/.sbtopts
```

For example, to configure JDK used by sbt in current project, try setting in `.sbtopts`

```
-java-home /Users/picard/.sdkman/candidates/java/current
```

Comment: This was the fix for me 100%, adding `-java-home /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home` at the bottom of `/usr/local/etc/sbtopts`.  You can also see what JDK your system is using at `/usr/libexec/java_home` to see if it's using a different JDK than you expect. You would want both to be the same Java version.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue recently. What worked for me is to install `SDKMAN`(https://sdkman.io/)

```sh
$ curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
...
$ source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
...
```

After installation, I wanted to see what versions of Java I can install. So I simply run this command to list all the available versions of Java

```sh
sdk list java
```

Choose the version you want to install (recommend installing either 8 or 11 as mentioned above) and simply run the command with the identifier that specifies your version from the list

```sh
sdk install java 11.0.3.hs-adpt
```

After installation, it set the Java 11 to default on my system. I then ran the `sbt` command again and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

This is what solved my problem on my Mac.

```
brew uninstall sbt
```

Install sdkman

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

Install sbt via sdk

```
sdk install sbt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SDKMAN then in some cases certain versions of Java (i.e. JDK) from different **vendor** might help.

E.g. I was using Amazon Correto JDK8 (version `8.332.08.1-amzn`) and it could not properly build my sbt project in IntellIJ IDEA, so I've switched to using Zulu's JDK8 (version `8.0.332-zulu`) as default java version.

Hope this helps and good luck. :)