# compiling my play scala project with openjdk 17 and openjdk 11

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

While compiling my play Scala project I saw the next error message:

> error: error while loading String, class file '/root/.sbt/1.0/java9-rt-ext-private_build_17_0_2/rt.jar(java/lang/String.class)' is broken
> (class java.lang.NullPointerException/Cannot invoke "scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.typerPhase()" because the return value of "scala.tools.nsc.Global.currentRun()" is null)

This happened while using openJdk17 and openJdk 11.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Play is for sure not compatible with Java 17 yet. But your error is related to compilation and SBT in general, not specific to Play.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SBT fails with \`String.class is broken\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61271015/sbt-fails-with-string-class-is-broken)